# Crear archivo txt en Descargas con Python

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear un archivo que contenga un texto. **El archivo se genera con éxito.** Pero necesito que este archivo se almacene en la carpeta de Descargas pero no logro encontrar cómo. Estoy trabajando con Windows 11. Aquí está el código:

```
    def process(expression, min_num, max_num, variable):

        l_process = summatory_p(expression, variable, min_num, max_num)
        s_process = ""

        for i in l_process:
            s_process += i
            s_process += "\n"

        with open('procedimiento.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(s_process)
        f.close
```

Comment: Verifica la indentación de tu código. Tal vez esté diferente en tu entorno, pero en su versión actual, todo está por fuera de la definición del método.

Comment: En el `open` puedes colocar el path completo del archivo.

Comment: Este sería el path `C:/Users/NOMBREUSUARIO/Downloads/'procedimiento.txt` pero qué pondría en NOMBREUSUARIO?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para encontrar el directorio del usuario actual de Windows usa `os.environ`. Luego concatena con `Downloads` (`Descargas` es solo un alias de `Downloads`) y con el `nombre_del_archivo`.

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['USERPROFILE']
'C:\\Users\\tu_usuario'
```

Entonces en tu código eso sería:

```py
import os

# ... 

file_dst = os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE'], 'Downloads', 'procedimiento.txt')
with open(file_dst, 'w') as f:
    # ... resto del código
```

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar los documentos en un directorio en concreto necesitas importar la librería `os` en concreto la función `path` la cual te permite especificar el path (dirección) donde vas a guardar tu archivo.

```
import os.path

#Aqui introduce la direccion donde deseas guardar el archivo.
save_path = 'C:/example/'

nombre_del_archivo = raw_input("Introduzca el nombre del archivo: ")

nombre_completo = os.path.join(save_path, nombre_del_archivo+".txt")         

file1 = open(nombre_completo, "w")

toFile = raw_input("Escribe lo que quieras aqui: ")

file1.write(toFile)

file1.close()
```

Este código ha sido extraído de StackOverflow en inglés, te dejo el link por si quieres consultar algo más o tienes dudas de algo de lo que he escrito.

[Guardar txt en un directorio personalizado con python (EN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024248/telling-python-to-save-a-txt-file-to-a-certain-directory-on-windows-and-mac)